# jQuery Data Table Headers - Set Width to the largest content size

Tags: jquery, datatables

What I want to be able to do is have a the column/header widths to always be the same width based on the content on the rows.

For example given the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>col 1</th>
            <th>col 2</th>
            <th>col 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>val 1</td>
            <td>val 2</td>
            <td>REALLY LONG VALUE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>val 1</td>
            <td>val 2</td>
            <td>val 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>val 1</td>
            <td>val 2</td>
            <td>val 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the width of the third column to always match the width of the first row's third td value even when it is not present in the rendered view.

I have tried setting the `autoWidth` option to false with no luck and haven't found the right configuration setting to achieve what I am looking to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue; what I needed to do was set the `autoWidth` option to `true` and also write a CSS rule similar to the following:

```
th > * {
  width: inherit;
}
```

DataTables was hardcoding a width to the `th` elements, but the children elements were overriding the parent `th`'s width for some reason... inheriting the parent `th` width seems to take care of this issue.